# Will unlock_time lock sender wallet balance?

Tags: transaction-unlock-time

I sent some transfers between two of my wallets yesterday with unlock_time about a month in the future. The incoming transfers show up in the new wallet as expected with the correct unlock time.

What also happened is that part of the balance in the wallet I sent it from is still locked. Will this balance also be locked for the same amount of time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it will be locked for the same amount of time.

This is because the wallet had split some of the inputs into 2 amounts: one which it sent to the destination, and one which it sent back to yourself as change. The amount which will be locked on the sending wallet will depend on what input was chosen by the wallet when sending, and duration will be the same.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Annoying if you're not aware of it however and lock up funds you were planning to use for something else.

Comment: That is horrible, I hope people don't get a huge amount of money locked in this way. This is a bug that needs to be fixed, right?

Comment: No, it's needed for privacy features to work. However note that it won't lock ALL your funds, and if you use the wallet often you should have enough various inputs for this locking to become less and less significant.